# List authors (scientists) by various attribute

Tags: review, peer-review-journal

Is there an easy way to list authors of biology articles by

- University
- country
- number of published articles
- sum of citations of all articles he/she wrote
- fields of study (population genetics)
- ...

For example, I want to know who are the 10 most popular/cited authors in population genetics in UK's universities. How can I achieve such search?

For example, do WebOfKnowledge provide such tools?

Please, let me know if this question should be asked on another SE website.

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question, but you might be interested to check out [Scholarometer](http://scholarometer.indiana.edu/), which aims to compare top researchers within and across scientific fields. This is based on a standardised h-index with data pulled from google scholar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that you can do this systematically in Web of Science but you can do it in an exploratory way.

Initial search: *Topic* - "population genetics" + *Address* - UK

sort by *Times cited* is probably more useful than the default (*newest to oldest*)

open *Authors* in sidebar - this is a list of the top 100 names
can refine to the top 10, or whatever

For example consider Brian Charlesworth:

1. Open an item with his name in the author list (he has some single author items)
2. Click on the link of his name to see his papers
3. Click on *Create citation report* to see charts of published items per year and citations per year

It may be that you know all this.